# AJAX calls with php using cURLs - 405 Method Not Found

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

I am trying to populate a table using an API and an AJAX call. Whenever I try to run the code while using my php file, which is meant to create a cURL session, I end up getting this message in the console. [405 Method Not Allowed + jqXHR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MGUo.jpg)

```
POST http://localhost:8080/task/libs/php/getCountryInfo.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ script.js:3
dispatch @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3
script.js:31 error : Method Not Allowed
script.js:32 {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/task/libs/php/getCountryInfo.php".
send @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ script.js:3
dispatch @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3
script.js:36 AJAX call completed
```

For the php file I've tried adding headers thinking that it was a CORS issue and hoped that it would go through, it did not.

I've tried replacing the url option within the AJAX call with the web address of the data populate the table with, this moves me onto a successful AJAX call however as I had written the call to use the php file it ends up getting stuck here as it cannot read the name portion `if (result.status.name === "ok")` of this as it is now undefined within this call.

I have tried commenting out this if statement to make it move on to the next bit anyway, only to have it again be unable to read as other parts are undefined in this case the 0 and the countryCode `$('#txtCountryCode').html(result['data'][0]['countryCode']);`

I've added all pages of code to this post, I can't think of what to try next, I'm not sure if there is something inherently wrong with the way I have written my AJAX call or the php routine I have linked it to. I'm just having a lot of trouble, any help would be much appreciated.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>GeoNames Task</title>
        <meta name="description" content="AJAX/PHP/CURL/JSON task">
        
        <link href="libs/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>API name</th>
                    <th>API description</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1. Country Info</td>
                    <td>Country:
                            <select id="selCountry">
                                <option value="GB">Great Britain</option>
                                <option value="FR">France</option>
                                <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                                <option value="US">USA</option>
                            </select>
                        Language:
                            <select id="selLanguage">
                                <option value="en">English</option>
                                <option value="fr">Francais</option>
                                <option value="de">Deutsche</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" id="btnOne">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="divResults">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="info">
                                        Country Code: 
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="txtCountryCode">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="info">
                                        Country: 
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="txtCountryName">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="info">
                                        Continent: 
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="txtContinent">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="info">
                                        Capital: 
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="txtCapital">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="info">
                                        Languages: 
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="txtLanguages">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="info">
                                        Population: 
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="txtPopulation">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="info">
                                        Area (km<sup>2</sup>):
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="txtArea">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/js/script.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

getCountryInfo.php

```
<?php 

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

$url='http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?formatted=true&lang=' . $_REQUEST['language'] . '&country=' . $_REQUEST['country'] . '&username=yajarobe&style=full';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($result,true);

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
$output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];

echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

script.js using php as url

```
$('#btnOne').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getCountryInfo.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            country: $('#selCountry').val(),
            language: $('#selLanguage').val()
        },
        //Successful AJAX call
        success: function(result) {

            console.log('AJAX call successful.');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

            if (result.status.name === "ok") {
            
                $('#txtCountryCode').html(result['data'][0]['countryCode']);
                $('#txtCountryName').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);
                $('#txtContinent').html(result['data'][0]['continent']);
                $('#txtCapital').html(result['data'][0]['capital']);
                $('#txtLanguages').html(result['data'][0]['languages']);
                $('#txtPopulation').html(result['data'][0]['population']);
                $('#txtArea').html(result['data'][0]['areaInSqKm']);
            
            }
        },
        //Error
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        },
        //Complete
        complete: function(){
            console.log('AJAX call completed');
        }
    });
});
```

script.js using API address as url

```
$('#btnOne').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?formatted=true&lang=' . $_REQUEST['language'] . '&country=' . $_REQUEST['country'] . '&username=yajarobe&style=full'",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            country: $('#selCountry').val(),
            language: $('#selLanguage').val()
        },
        //Successful AJAX call
        success: function(result) {

            console.log('AJAX call successful.');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

            //if (result.status.name === "ok") {
            
                $('#txtCountryCode').html(result['data'][0]['countryCode']);
                $('#txtCountryName').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);
                $('#txtContinent').html(result['data'][0]['continent']);
                $('#txtCapital').html(result['data'][0]['capital']);
                $('#txtLanguages').html(result['data'][0]['languages']);
                $('#txtPopulation').html(result['data'][0]['population']);
                $('#txtArea').html(result['data'][0]['areaInSqKm']);
            
            //}
        },
        //Error
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        },
        //Complete
        complete: function(){
            console.log('AJAX call completed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The AJAX request returns a 405? Or the curl request? It isn't clear, from your description

Comment: 405 is Method Not Allowed, that has no direct connection to CORS. And your attempts at using CORS headers in the PHP script are absolutely pointless - you are requesting a relative URL with your AJAX, so this is not cross-origin to begin with. CORS would only be relevant in the second case, where you try to make the AJAX request for the remote URL directly. But in that case, _they_ would have to respond with the headers allowing a CORS request, that is not for you to decide in the first place.

Comment: `thinking that it was a CORS issue`...why would it be a CORS issue? Did you actually get a CORS error in the browser's Console? Looking at the PHP URL you've used in $.ajax it appears to be on the same origin so there's no reason why you should have a CORS issue. Don't guess, do some debugging and investigation instead.

Comment: Best guess: `http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?...` wants to be requested via GET instead of POST ...? You already put the parameters into the query string, so why send them again as POST parameters.

Comment: Ok so if the Ajax is returning a 405 directly then _probably_ it's a config error in the webserver rather than PHP